# Why I can't remove element of arraylist

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist

```
class ScheduleUpdateDialog(private val schedules: ArrayList<Schedule>)
    : DialogFragment() {
    ...
    inner class DialogListener : DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
        override fun onClick(dialog: DialogInterface?, which: Int) {
            when(which) {
                DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE -> {
                    val content = calendarScheduleText.text.toString()
                    if(content != "") {
                        db.collection("schedules").document(id!!)
                            .update("content", content)
                        schedule.content = content
                        mainActivity.onDialogClick()
                    }
                }
                DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL -> {
                    db.collection("schedules").document(id!!)
                        .delete()
                    schedules.removeAt(index!!)
                    mainActivity.onDialogClick()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You *can* remove elements from an `ArrayList`. Why do you believe you cannot?

Comment: can you share your error if you get an error

Answer (score 0):

You can check return value for the element that has been removed.

> `abstract fun removeAt(index: Int): E`

**Removes** an element at the specified index from the list.

**Return** the element that has been removed.